# How to move character from one line into beggining of another in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, editing

I have *srt subtitles, and I need to move some characters from one line to the beggining of another.

Example:

```
aaaaaaaaa w 
aaaaaaaaaaa
```

And the result should be

```
aaaaaaaaa
w aaaaaaaaa
```

Tried

```
Find what:    w\r
Replace with:  \nw
```

But that gives me

```
aaaaaaaaa
w
aaaaaaaaa
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you intend to only move the trailing character `w` to the next line, or if other things need to move, but the following find and replace seems to be working in NPP:

```
Find:    (.*?) (\w)\R(\S+)
Replace: $1\n$2 $3
```

For the input:

```
aaaaaaaaa w
aaaaaaaaaaa
```

This generated the following output:

```
aaaaaaaaa
w aaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: One more thing - I need to ignore numbers, because yiur command moves numbers from timestamps, that's bad.

Comment: @Nope Try: `(?!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?) (\w)\R(\S+)` ... this adds a negative lookahead which would exclude any line beginning with a timestamp text.

Comment: Ok, that works. It looks like I also need to move 2 and 3 characters words, but also from the end of lines. How to achieve that?

Comment: You should ask a follow-up question if you still need more help.  Please don't change your question after it has already been answered.